# Showing $\lambda$ is zero where $\det(B-\lambda I) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I managed to come to the end of a proof regarding a determinant of a linear operator. However, I stuck at the end. I know it is kinda simple but I couldn't see it right away.

Here is my previous work:

$F$ is a field. $V = M_{nxn}(F)$ is a vector space of $nxn$ matrices over $F$, and $B$ is some arbitrary element in $V$. Now, we are given a linear operator $T:V \rightarrow V$ defined by $T(A) = AB - BA$. We wish to show that $det(T)=0$.

Here is my attempt:

If $T$ has an $0$ as eigenvalue, then by $p(x)=det(T-\lambda I)$, $p(0)=det(T)=0$. Thus, showing that $\lambda = 0$ would suffice.

We split into cases.

Case 1: $B$ is invertible.

Then choose $A=B^{-1}$, we have $T(A)=0=0*A$, so $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue.

Case 2: $B$ is not invertible.

Let $A$ be a nonzero matrix, and $\lambda \in F$
$$T(A)=AB-BA= \lambda A$$
$$\lambda A - AB = -BA$$
$$A \lambda - AB = -BA$$
$$A(\lambda I - B) = -BA$$
Take determinants of each side,
$$det(A(\lambda I - B)) = det(-BA)$$
$$det(A)det(\lambda I - B) = (-1)^n det(B)det(A)$$
Since $B$ is not invertible, $det(B)=0$, so,
$$det(A)det(\lambda I - B)=0$$

Here we have:
$$det(B-\lambda I) = 0$$
It is clear that $\lambda$ can be zero. However, how can I show that $\lambda$ must be zero?

Comment: There is not enough information to show that $\lambda$ must be zero. The equation holds **iff** $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Comment: Are these the only conditions? If so then $\lambda$ is not necessarily zero: consider $$B 
= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\  0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ where $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda = 1$ both work

Comment: I am sorry let me add my previous work.

Comment: Do you know if $B$ is nilpotent? I.e. if $B^m = 0$ for some $m$?

Comment: @Improve We have no info regarding that. Added the previous steps.

Comment: What does $V$ mean?

Comment: @Improve $V = M_{nxn}(F)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = I_{n \times n}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Also, based on your approach. If $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$, then $T$ has eigenvectors

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$

with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ respectively, so you cannot show that $\lambda$ must be zero.

Comment: Oh well, that was so simple. How couldn't I think of it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since it is not true in general. For instance, take $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Then $\det(B-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=\lambda^2-\lambda$. Yes, it is $0$ when $\lambda=0$, but also when $\lambda=1$.

Comment: Here I have added the previous steps.